# How to change innerText of multiple buttons by a class name in Jquery or JS?

Tags: javascript

How to change innerText of multiple buttons by a class name for example on this website https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_pricing_table.asp
The class name here is "button w3-hover-green".

I tried running

```
    function myFunction()
{
x=document.getElementsByClassName("button w3-hover-green");  // Find the elements
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i].innerText="Hello JavaScript!";    // Change the content
    }

}
```

but it doesn't change the text "Sign Up".

Comment: It works. Perhaps you forgot to call your function?

Comment: That's correct! I am new to JS and didn't call it.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't call the function in Chrome's console.

It should be:

```js
function myFunction() {
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("button w3-hover-green");  // Find the elements
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerText="Hello JavaScript!"; // Change the content
  }
}
    
myFunction();
```

Comment: You can also simplify it: `[...document.getElementsByClassName("button w3-hover-green")].forEach(button => button.innerText = "Hello JavaScript!");`